# jQuery mobile and collapsible data performance

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-mobile

I am using collapsible headers with jquery mobile and noticed that there is a performance issue with the iPad. Is there a limit of collapsible headers that should be used on a page. I have a page with about 30 collapsible sections and the page itself is slow on an iPad (there is a lag when scrolling). Opening and closing a section take a couple seconds each time.

I've seen a couple other posts about this issue (with far less collapsible headers on a page) but no real answers.

Comment: Which jqm version are you using?

Comment: The idea is to not use js/jquery for any animations but use CSS(3) to animate DOM elements whenever it is possible. CSS3 can take advantage of hardware acceleration

Comment: @roasted How does that help with the question?

Comment: @alkis  Isn't OP using kind of animation with jquery? If yes, he should think about using CSS3 transition/animation instead. Just my personnal opinion

Comment: @roasted I was not being offensive (I just read my comment and I felt like clarifying that). It's just that IMHO the OP is asking in relevance to jqm not in general.

Comment: @alkis np. That's why i posted it (about CSS3) as comment, not as answer.

Comment: ver 1.3.1. I'll investigate the CSS3 solution, do you have any examples?